# Why would you have an Elliptic Curve where coordinates of points lie on a different group as opposed to the field over which the curve is defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

Normally, when you define an Elliptic Curve over a field $F$ - it means that the coefficients of the Curve equation lie in field $F$. However, in most cases, I have seen that even the $x$ & $y$ coordinates of the points on the curve also lie in the same field.

I am reading up on Torsion Points from "Mathematical Cryptography" by Jeffrey Hoffstein, Jill Pipher & Joseph H. Silverman & I found that the above isn't true in all cases.

> Let $m \ge 1$ be an integer. A point $P \in E$ satisfying $mP =
>  \mathcal{O}$ is called a point of order $m$ in the group $E$. We
> denote the set of points of order $m$ by $E[m] = \{P \in E : [m]P =
>  \mathcal {O} \}$. Such points are called points of finite order or
> torsion points. It is easy to see that if $P$ and $Q$ are in $E[m]$,
> then $P + Q$ and $−P$ are also in $E[m]$, so $E[m]$ is a subgroup of
> $E$. If we want the coordinates of $P$ to lie in a particular field
> $K$, for example in $Q$ or $R$ or $C$ or $F_p$, then we write
> $E(K)[m]$.

From this, it seems as if the group where the coordinates of the points lie may be different from the field over which the curve equation itself is defined.

Why you would want to do this & why would you want to do this for Torsion Points?

Comment: Because it gives interesting subgroups of the big group $E(\overline{F})$.

Comment: The points in $E[m}$ usually lie in the algebraic closure of $E$.

Comment: @Wuestenfux - do none of the points of $E(m) lie in original field?

Comment: The neutral point does – and then it depends a lot on the field. For instance, on $\mathbb{Q}$, there is no nontrivial $n$-torsion point defined on $\mathbb{Q}$ for $n \geq 13$.

Comment: Consider a simpler setting: do you see any value in considering the roots of a polynomial in $F[x]$ that are not already in $F$ itself, such as roots of polynomials in $\mathbf Q[x]$ that are not rational numbers?

Comment: @KCd - I under algebraic closure. But if you were just interested in more points, you would always have all points of all elliptic curves in $F^{ac}$ or $C$ irrespective of which field the curve itself is defined over. But the norm is usually to have the points in the same field as the curve coordinates. Why are torsion points not following this norm? In what situations do you do this?

Comment: Is the polynomial $x^2+2$ a polynomial with rational coefficients, real coefficients, or complex coefficients? Answer: yes. The claim that "the norm is usually to have the points on the same field as the curve coordinates" is either false, or misses the point: if you are allowing points to have entries in $\mathbb{R}$, then you *are* considering points with coordinates in $\mathbb{R}$, same as all other points you are considering. If you mean "the field of definition of the curve" (the smallest field which contains all *coefficients*), then your assertion about the norm is quite simply false.

Comment: (cont) Because we consider solutions in larger fields *all the time*. Just as Keith Conrad notes, we do that with polynomials; and we don't just jump all the way to the algebraic closure always: we often are interested only in some intermediate fields. The same is true with elliptic curves. We *can* talk about just the rational points for a curve defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ (there is an entire book by Tate and Silverman called "Rational Points on Elliptic Curves"). But the structure is then restricted (Thm of Mazur); going to larger fields gives you more available structures.

Comment: Could you provide a more complete reference, @user93353 ? I'm pretty sure there are hundreds of books titled "Mathematical Cryptography". Even the notation $P \in E$ is not clear to me. Do they mean $P \in E(F)$ or $P \in E(\overline{F})$? I guess it must be the latter, but presumably the book states their conventions.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin - Rational point doesn't necessarily mean that the group where the point's coordinates lie are different from the field where the Curve equations coefficients lie. i.e. Curve could be defined over $R$ & the points also could lie on $R$. So I am confused as to how that is relevant

Comment: @ViktorVaughn - Authors are Jeffrey Hoffstein, Jill Pipher & Joseph H. Silverman

Comment: Really $E[m]$ is an $F$-group scheme, so one can form the set $E[m](S)$ of $S$-points for any $F$-scheme $S$. Books that don't want to introduce group schemes often just take $E[m]$ to be $E[m](\overline{F})$ since one can recover $E[m](F)$ as the set of Galois invariants $E[m](\overline{F})^{Gal(\overline{F}/F)}$ and $E[m](L)$ as $E[m](\overline{F})^{Gal(\overline{F}/L)}$ for any field extension $F \subseteq L \subseteq \overline{F}$.

Comment: @user93353 You should add that information to your question. Also, I don't think you've included the complete title. That said, I think the book is quite imprecise in its definitions. Even their definition of an elliptic curve as "...the set of solutions of a Weierstrass equation..." just makes me ask "solutions in what ring"?

Comment: It's relevant when the curve is defined over the rationals... But in any case. Your entire question is premised on a false belief that "the norm" is to work only in the field of definiton. I don't know where you got that idea from, but it is completely false.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin - I am reading Elliptic Curves from a Cryptography point of view & till now, for ECDH & other uses I have read about, both the points on the curve & the coordinates of the equation both are in the same field. I am now reading about Torsion points (in the chapter on Pairings) & this is the first time I came across it differing. Hence the question. But as you say, it may not be the norm.

Comment: One often considers fields other than the *smallest* field containing the coefficients (that is, the field of definition). One may consider any field that contains the field of definition, and often we do. One may even start by looking at a particular field, and the extend to a larger field for any number of reasonsn and, again, we often do, just like with roots of polynomials.

Comment: For a concrete answer relevant to cryptography, using a larger field is essential for pairing-based cryptography, because over a prime field, the pairing is trivial, which makes it useless for cryptography. You could, of course, define the curve over the larger field to begin with, but a prime field makes for a more efficient pairing. You cannot use an algebraic closure here, because cryptography (or anything computational, really) requires a finite field. All of this is explained in Chapter 6 of Hoffstein, Pipher, and Silverman.

Comment: algebraic geometry really should be done over an algebraically closed field